# Qt4/Qt5/Gtk2/Gtk3 font hinting consistency

Tags: fonts, qt5

I'm using Linux Manjaro with Xfce 4.10. I'm having a problem with font rendering.

This is an example of a Qt4 application:

[image]

Other program, in Gtk 2:

[image]

Yet another program, in Gtk 3:

[image]

So far so good, everything is consistent. **But then, Qt5 happened**:

[image]

The Qt5 font seems to be the same as if I change default font hinting to "Medium". I'd like Qt5 to behave like any other toolkit, that is to have a "Light" hinting.

How can I change this Qt5 behavior?

*Edit:* I would be very grateful even for a simple *hint* where to look, I don't even expect the whole solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be [QTBUG-27106](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-27106), seems to depend on Qt build configuration. You might also try [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1350501#p1350501).

Comment: From the QTBUG link, Marc Henning's comment with an example font configuration xml file fixed the hinting. The font is still slightly different, but it's way better than it was before.